# Halide extern methods

Tags: c++, halide

I use AOT compilation to use Halide code without Halide libraries.

I see in HalideRuntime.h (Available on the sources) that I have many extern methods availables in my .o files.

*halide_dev_malloc* and *halide_dev_free* are very instresting. I already use *halide_copy_to_dev* without problem, but I see that my memory was allocated. 
If I want to do a simple memcpy between host and device and use halide_dev_malloc instead, is this possible?

Did HalideRuntime.h group all the extern functions available or the object files contains a lot of others?

Jay

Answer (score 2):

HalideRuntime.h is intended to document all the routines that can be called or replaced by clients. There are many other symbols in the runtime, but they should be considered internal. We recently moved these other routines into their own namespace to indicate that they are internal.

The runtime for device backends is still a work in progress and there will be an improved design intended to allow more flexibility and to allow code to do more while still working generically across multiple backends. At present, halide_dev_malloc will allocate the device handle for whichever device backend is selected via the Target at Halide compile time. However, this handle is backend specific and thus in order to do anything with it you must know which backend is used and how that backend interacted with the device API. E.g. in order to use the handle with memcpy, you need to know that the device backend supports some sort of uniform memory architecture ("Unified Virtual Address Space" in CUDA terminology)and the device memory was allocated with the right API calls to make a memory buffer that can be accessed from both the device and CPU with the same pointer, etc. Depending on which backend you are using and which platform you are on, that may or may not work out at present. (Uniform memory designs are a fairly recent thing for the most part. We haven't put a lot of effort into supporting them.)

For CUDA/PTX, halide_dev_malloc calls cuMemAlloc and I think it may be in Unified Virtual Address Space on many systems by default, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use halide_dev_malloc and copy things yourself manually. See https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/src/runtime/cuda.cpp line 466 for what halide_copy_to_dev actually does.

First it does a halide_dev_malloc, and then uses cuda's cuMemcpyHtoD. There's a bunch of extra logic there in case the buffer isn't dense in memory, but most of the time it turns into a single cuMemcpyHtoD.

I believe HalideRuntime.h contains all the useful extern functions. There are a few other internal ones like halide_create_cuda_context that might conceivably be interesting. To see all of them, look for functions marked as WEAK that start with the name halide_ in this folder: https://github.com/halide/Halide/tree/master/src/runtime

Or you can run nm on a halide-generated object file and see all the symbols that start with halide_.